# How to change selector :contains to exact match one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line

`$('#custom-table tr > td:nth-child(1):contains('+val+')').closest('tr').show();`

and would like to find a way to have equal or exact match instead of contains.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet?

Comment: can you please provide the relevent html ??

Comment: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zaga/u372rfyd/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter)** and **[`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text)**

```js
var val = 'abc';
$('#custom-table tr > td:nth-child(1)').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == val;
  // get text content using text() and compare
  // and use $.trim() for removing whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.
}).closest('tr').show();
```

```css
#custom-table tr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="custom-table">
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>absc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcd</td>
    <td>abcd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>absc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcd</td>
    <td>abcd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update :** For exactly same behaviour

```js
var val = 'abc';
$('#custom-table tr > td:nth-child(1)').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf( val)  != -1;
  // get text content using text() and compare
  // and use indexOf() for checking string contains the value.
}).closest('tr').show();
```

```css
#custom-table tr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="custom-table">
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>absc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcd</td>
    <td>abcd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>absc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcd</td>
    <td>abcd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried to add this function along selectize.js, but it does not work for me. Here is [jsFiddle link] (http://jsfiddle.net/zaga/u372rfyd/5/)

I try to make selected xAB return AB lines only, not ABB one.

Comment: In that case you need to use indexof..... above method only work for exact match...... I will update the answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#custom-table tr > td:nth-child(1)').find("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === val;
}).closest('tr').show();
```